# Which balloon goes to Suicune?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

I love the 3 legendary dogs, but my favorite is Suicune. I need to know which balloon goes to it.

Comment: Please do not spam the site with every Pokémon you like, instead use the ressources linked in the answers to find the other Pokémon you want.

Answer (score 2):

Suicune is the boss of the [Purifying Pond](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/locations/goldplateau.shtml#purifyingpond), in the [Gold Plateau](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/locations/goldplateau.shtml). He is visible if you start the level with three stars.

To get the Gold Balloon, you must have an Adventure Rank greater or equal to 10, and buy it in the Balloon Shop for 30 PokéDiamonds.